# Flutter: how to conditionally run method inside ChangeNotifier after calling constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

```
class MyChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool myVar;
  ...
  MyChangeNotifier({@required this.myVar, ...});

  void myFunction (){...}
  ...
```

I would like to have an initState-like function to call as soon as the Constructor is finished running.

```
if (myVar) {
  myFunction();
}
```

How can I get this behavior? It doesn't seem that ChangeNotifier has initState, because I get "The method 'initState' isn't defined in a superclass of 'MyChangeNotifier'" when I write the following:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
}
```

I thought about calling the function from outside, immediately after creating MyChangeNotifier, but I am not sure where to do so:

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyChangeNotifier>(
  create: (context) => MyChangeNotifier(
    myVar: true,
    ...
  ),
  child: ... )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you call myFunction from the constructor

```
MyChangeNotifier({@required this.myVar, ...}){
  if (myVar) {
    myFunction();
  }
};
```

note that ChangeNotifier is not a StatefulWidget to have an initState